# javascript variable use outside function

Tags: javascript

```
$scope.pagination_data = function(page_data){
   count = page_data.data.count;
};

console.log("outside count is",count);// this not working

var page = function(){
 userService.paginate()
  .then(function(user){
    $scope.pagination_data(user);
    console.log("count is",count);//this is works
  });
};
```

in that code i m using $http service by using that i m getting data aftr that i want a count then i m getting count also but now i want this count variable access in controller but this is not accessible to me. what should i do..?

Comment: You're logging the value before you call the function.

Comment: either declare `count` outside of the function, or just `return count;` the use it like that

Comment: @yoavmatchulsky Returning a value from an asynchonous function is useless.

Comment: oh, I thought he only wanted the value inside the promise. my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, both works but you're calling the first one at the wrong time.

The `.then()` indicates that `paginate()` returns a promise. Which should be a hint that it is asynchronous.

To prove this, delay calling your first console.log by using `setTimeout`:

```
$scope.pagination_data = function(page_data){
   count = page_data.data.count;
};

setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("outside count is",count);// this should work
}, 5000); // wait 5 seconds before calling the code above
// If 5 seconds is not long enough increase it to 10 or something

var page = function(){
 userService.paginate()
  .then(function(user){
    $scope.pagination_data(user);
    console.log("count is",count);//this is works
  });
};
```

What is asynchronous code? Asynchronous simply means that the code will be called later. What `paginate().then()` does is not call the `function(user)` function immediately but rather remembers that it is supposed to call `function(user)` (which then calls your `pagination_data` function to set the value of `count`) at a later time. It then continues on running other stuff.

When there's no other code to run, the event loop gets processed and whatever `userService.paginate()` needs to do asynchronously gets processed.

When whatever `userService.paginate()` is waiting for finally returns (this may be a network request, user click etc) the `function(user)` function finally gets called. This in turn calls `$scope.pagination_data()` which is what assigns the result to the global `count` variable.

What does that `setTimeout()` do? Well, it does the same thing I describe above. Instead of calling `console.log()` immediately it remembers to call it later. Then when 5 seconds (5000 milliseconds) expires, and there is no other javascript code running (this is important because it means javascript can run the event loop), the `console.log()` finally gets called.

Comment: thnks dear..bt could i used that count variable directly with other operations like i want to calculate page size so var page_size = count / limit ; is this fine

Comment: Put all those other code inside the `function(user)` function like you did your second `console.log()`. That's the **only** way to do it. It's the nature of asynchronous programming

Answer (score 0):

Just define the variable outside.

```
var count = 0;
$scope.pagination_data = function(page_data){
   count = page_data.data.count;
};

console.log("outside count is",count);// this not working

var page = function(){
 userService.paginate()
  .then(function(user){
    $scope.pagination_data(user);
    console.log("count is",count);//this is works
  });
};
```

Comment: i m defining varable outside also bt not getting count

Comment: check what values you get inside the pagination_data function by logging them out. I guess you never initialize them

Comment: first i am initialize count variable to zero.

Answer (score 0):

The fist statement only defines the function, it doesn't call it. If you have data to pass to that function call it before logging the count.

```
   // this only defines the function, doesn't call it
    $scope.pagination_data = function(page_data){
       count = page_data.data.count;
    };

    console.log("outside count is",count);// count is still unset

    var page = function(){
     userService.paginate()
      .then(function(user){
        $scope.pagination_data(user); // this is the call, count will be set
        console.log("count is",count);//this will work
      });
    };
```

Comment: k..bt now i m changing the sequence also still not getting count

Comment: var page = function(){
     userService.paginate()
      .then(function(user){
        $scope.pagination_data(user);
        console.log("count is",count);
      });
  };

   
$scope.pagination_data = function(page_data){
   count = page_data.data.count;
};

 console.log("outside count is",count);